# Modify Progressive Web App background colour

Tags: android, css, json, progressive-web-apps

I have a Progressive Web App which is capable of being added to home screen. When the home screen icon is tapped (on mobile) there is a (kind of) welcome page with icon that appears before opening the actual app.

I have set the background colour of that welcome screen to be blue in `menifest.json`. I need to make it brown. I have modified the `menifest.json` file and updated the website. But the mobile seems to have cached it permanently and it is still showing blue.

I have refreshed page many times and added the web app to home screen multiple times. But it is never changing.

I have also changed the cache name in `service-worker.js`. Yet no luck!

Comment: Just thinking: try clearing your browser cache. When serving the manifest, try to set headers for a proper caching policy.

Answer (score 2):

1. Plug in your device
2. visit chrome://inspect
3. Inspect the device / tab you are looking at for your site
4. In DevTools go to Network tab
5. Select 'Disable Cache'
6. Refresh your web app
7. Then try adding to homescreen

If you get the correct color it's a good indicator that your previous manifest was cached and you should consider a caching strategy, either file re-visioning the manifest.json file (i.e. manifest.12345.json) OR set appropriate headers.

One thing to note: on Android there is no way to update the icon / manifest details once it's added to homescreen - this is a known issue / bug.